# WordML binary to file conversion

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, dita

I'm planning an XSLT transformation to some WordML documents (2003) to DITA. Fairly straight forward... except, I need to save the inline binary of the png file (in the  tag) as a file at a level above the XML output file. Is it possible to output to a png in XSLT, or am I going to have to process it through a Java program first?

Comment: XSLT cannot be used to output arbitrary binary values -- even if XML 1.1 is used, the value 0x00 is still illegal. You will need to write and call a small extension function that would take the encoded string, do the decoding and write the raw binary into the file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the WordML has inline binary? I think your assumption there is incorrect. It is likely base64 encoded data. We've done that before and I dug out the code her that generates DITA from WordML, the image is stuffed into the "src" attribute using its base64 encoded bytes:

```
<image>
<xsl:variable name="srcfile" select="concat('/word/',string($rels/rel:Relationships/rel:Relationship[@Id = $src]/@Target))"/>
<xsl:variable name="imagepkg" select="//pkg:part[@pkg:name=$srcfile]"/>
<xsl:variable name="attachmentContentType" select="$imagepkg/@pkg:contentType"/>
<xsl:variable name="encodedImageBytes" select="$imagepkg/pkg:binaryData/text()"/>                        
<xsl:variable name="scale">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="w:r/w:drawing/wp:inline/a:graphic/a:graphicData/pic:pic/pic:spPr/a:ln/@w">
            <xsl:value-of select="number(w:r/w:drawing/wp:inline/a:graphic/a:graphicData/pic:pic/pic:spPr/a:ln/@w)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$defscale"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:attribute name="width">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(string(number(w:r/w:drawing/descendant::wp:extent/@cx div ($scale * 96))),'in')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="height">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(string(number(w:r/w:drawing/descendant::wp:extent/@cy div ($scale * 96))),'in')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:text>data:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$attachmentContentType"/>                
    <xsl:text>;base64,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$encodedImageBytes"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</image>
```

You could put all the base64 encoded information into a separate file if you want, but the binary data is not in the WordML. If you want it in one step with external files, you could write a java extension function (assuming you are using java XSLT like Saxon) and pass in the base64 encoded image, the function would decode and write to disk.